# "windows-1256" encoding in mac OS

Tags: macos, encoding, utf-8

I wanna read a file in "windows-1256" encoding on mac OS, and then convert it to "utf-8".
how is this possible?
I have done this before in windows, by notepad++, but now I think my mac can't recognise the "windows-1256" encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the program, many editors can handle most encodings just fine, or try

```
iconv -f windows-1256 < oldfile >newfile
```

... provided it's just a text file, not binary.